# How to make a control from a StackPanel visible on top of another control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, stackpanel, expander

In my window I have a `DockPanel` with a `StackPane`l holding a custom UserControl on the left, and a Grid with a ListBox on the right. My UserControl contains an `Expander` with a ListBox.

This is the code from the window:

```xml
<Window ...>
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <localp:NeumesPanel/> <!-- This is the UserControl -->
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Margin="10" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <ListBox .../>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Right now, when I expand the Expander, part of it doesn't show since the StackPanel's Width is narrower than the Width of Expander's content. Like this: http://screenshooter.net/100101493/xfcfxau

What I'd like to achieve is to have the Expander show over my Grid without compromising on the Grid's Width - I don't want the StackPanel wider than it currently is. How to do it? Is it possible?

Comment: Using the `StackPanel` there could cause you problems as they don't resize their children like `Grid`s do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Karl Shifflet has done something like that: [Expander with popup](http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2008/02/05/wpf-sample-series-expander-control-with-popup-content/)

Summary of the solution:

> - Wrap the `Expander` control inside a `Canvas` control.
> - Constrain the `Canvas` height to the desired height when the `Expander` control is
>     collapsed.
> - Set the `Canvas` `Panel.ZIndex` higher than controls you want
>     to overlay.
> - Style and design your `Expander` `Content` so that it looks
>     like a `PopUp`.

Edit:

In your case, you need to set the `Panel.ZIndex` on the `StackPanel` containing your `UserControl`.

Comment: Thanks! It works when I both set the Panel.ZIndex on the StackPanel and wrap the Expander into a Canvas.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, using the `StackPanel` there could cause you problems as they don't resize their children like `Grid`s do. Furthermore, a `StackPanel` won't let you display content outside its bounds. The `Canvas` control on the other hand will, if you set the `ClipToBounds` property to `False`.

Here is a very simple example that shows how you can do this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Canvas Background="Blue" Width="100" ClipToBounds="False">
        <Border Background="Red" Width="200" Height="50" Panel.ZIndex="10" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

[image]